# How do I prevent incoming call notifications on a non-primary iPhone?

Tags: iphone, notifications

I am using an iPhone 6S as my primary work iPhone. I have an old iPhone 4 that I am trying to use as a dedicated baby monitor.

The iPhone 4 has had its SIM card removed, but it maintains WiFi access to our network.

Both are using the same apple ID.

Whenever my iPhone 6S receives a phone call, my iPhone 4 still shows an incoming call. I have gone into phone notifications and disabled everything. I'm not sure what else to disable to prevent it from ringing. Any ideas?

Both are running the latest IOS (10.3.1).

Comment: What happens when you sign out of your Apple ID on the iPhone 4?  Does it still ring?

Comment: Have you tried: on your phone with the SIM, Settings > Phone > calls on other devices.  Turn off for all or for the other phone in question.

Comment: By disabled everything do you mean do not disturb is also set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this same problem, and fixed it by first turning off iCloud Drive. *This fixes the shared call history between devices.* Second, go to Settings -> Phone -> Calls on Other Devices -> Off *This fixes calls ringing up between devices*

In your case, you could also avoid the problem by turning on Do Not Disturb on the iPhone 4 — that will stop all notifications. It is found in Settings -> Do Not Disturb

Comment: The OP has an iPhone 4 which can't be updated past iOS 7 (I think it's 7.1.2 but don't recall the exact minor version).  It can't run iOS 10.3.   Please edit your answer for the OPs iOS version.